# How do I send request and recieve response from REST API using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest, api

I have a local server running on my computer which has an in-built REST API. the base url of api is: http://127.0.0.1:8090/ehr/api/v1 . Now I want to make a client application for this server using this api. To log in this server, the api url is baseurl/login with POST method. It takes username, password and organization as parameters and returns an auth token in json if the login is successful. Now I want to create a form in html and javascript which will ask the username, password, organization and log in the user if response is an auth token, otherwise if the response in an error instead of token, user will not be able to log in. What should be the html and javascript code for this form? I typed the following code to output the auth token but it showed no result. even the console log is empty.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="u" placeholder="Username" id="username" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" id="password" required="required" />
        <input type="text" name="p" placeholder="Organization" id="organization" required="required" />
        <button type="submit" onclick="loginfunc()">Let me in.</button>

    </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        function loginfunc(){
            var baseurl = "http://localhost:8090/ehr/api/v1";
            var funcurl = "/login";
            var username = document.getElementById("username");
            var password = document.getElementById("password");
            var organization = document.getElementById("organization");
            var url = baseurl+funcurl+"?username="+username+"&password="+password+"&organization="+organization
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open( "POST", url, true); // false for synchronous request
            xmlHttp.send( null );
            var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.write(response)
        }
    </script>

</body></html>
```

edit: I changed the login function based on suggestions to this:

```
function loginfunc(){
                var baseurl = "http://localhost:8090/ehr/api/v1";
                var funcurl = "/login";
                var username = document.getElementById("username");
                var password = document.getElementById("password");
                var organization = document.getElementById("organization");
                var url = baseurl+funcurl+"?username="+username+"&password="+password+"&organization="+organization;
                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if(xmlHttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
                        console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
                    }
                };
                xmlHttp.open( "POST", url, true); // false for synchronous request              
                xmlHttp.send( null );
                document.write(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
```

but now I get 401 unauthorized error at xmlHttp.send() function. I can't understand why as when I make request to same url using a REST client like insomnia, it works fine and returns auth token.

Comment: See the answer given by Nimrod, You can use callback to execute the code after post request.

Comment: please take a look at edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The request you're making to the server is asynchronous, so your code cannot just take the response immediately. This is done using a callback:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xmlHttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
  }
};
```

Comment: can you tell exactly what I have to edit in the code since I was totally unaware of this callback concept you just wrote about.

Comment: If you put exactly the code I wrote just before your `xmlHttp.send(null)`, you should see the response in the console.

Comment: Is your server expecting a POST by any chance?

Comment: yes, the documentation states that /login is a POST request

Comment: it wants localhost:8090/ehr/api/v1/login as url and username, password and organization as parameters in POST request.

Comment: I think you need to put the parameters into the `send` method as a string parameter instead of attaching them to the url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158248/discussion-between-nimrod-argov-and-dreadedharvester).